# add_options_page in a named function

Tags: php, wordpress

I have to perform this action:

```
add_action('admin_menu', function(){
    add_options_page(
        'Submissions of MAIN page contact form', 
        'Submissions of MAIN page contact form', 
        'manage_options',
        'ea_submissions2', 
        news()
    );
});
```

In PHP 5.2 anonymous functions are not supported, so I made the following:

```
function news_opt(){
    add_options_page(
        'Submissions of MAIN page contact form', 
        'Submissions of MAIN page contact form', 
        'manage_options',
        'ea_submissions2', 
        news()
    );
}
add_action('admin_menu', news_opt());
```

And after that I got **Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_options_page()** error. What is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you append `()`, you're calling the execution of a function. **And** it has to be passed as a string:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'news_opt' );
```

And

```
add_options_page( ..., ..., 'news' );
```

The documentation for [`add_options_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_options_page) and [`admin_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_menu) would have shown that. When some WordPress function or hook doesn't work, always check if the Codex has useful information.